# Android: DOM XML parser that supports FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING?

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, jaxb

We have a requirement that our XML parser must support `XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING`.

Unfortunately, the XML parser that is bundled with Android does not. I cannot find any XML packages that conform to this standard - do any exist?

So far:

- [Xerces is not supported on Android](https://code.google.com/p/xerces-for-android/).
- [dom4j](https://github.com/dom4j/dom4j) does not contain a `DocumentBuilder` or `DocumentBuilderFactory`?

Answer (score 1):

'xerces-for-android' did the trick. We can use the `SetFeature` method from `DocumentBuilderFactory` of xerces to apply `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING`.

Had to download source and build the jar from; https://code.google.com/p/xerces-for-android/

Comment: Is there a way to convert the Document object from xerces to Document object type of Javan.parsers.Document?