# DocumentBuilderFactory cannot setFeature FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING

Tags: java, android, security, owasp, xxe

I am trying to create an instance of DocumentBuilderFactory with `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` set to `true`. I keep getting ParserConfigurationException when I am trying to setFeature.

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try{
            factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e){ //Always gets here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Is that an Android thing? The JRE requires it. At least it requires it now - a very old parser implementation may not support it.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline, yes its Android.

Comment: Googling gives this SO other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337995/android-dom-xml-parser-that-supports-feature-secure-processing . Looks like a rather poor show on Google's part.

Comment: Not planning to use any 3-rd part library in my source code. 

After more investigation - it seems like Android's version of DBF is sort of stripped by Google and therefore they suggest to use "XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING", not sure if secure processing is actually helps to avoid XXE attacks. The only documentation left by Google on this constant:`instructs the implementation to process XML securely. This may set limits on XML constructs to avoid conditions such as denial of service attacks.`
https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/XMLConstants#FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING